# Python/Pygame importing fonts trouble

Tags: python, fonts, import, ioerror

I'm trying to use a font in a game I'm trying to build. The font name is SansitaOne.
Unfortunately pygame doesn't let me import it.

```
pygame.font.init()
myfont = pygame.font.Font("incAssests/fonts/SansitaOne.tff",25)
```

The error I get is: IOError: unable to read font filename
eventhough I've checked numerous times that that is the correct directory.

As well, the example given to me is.

```
font = pygame.font.Font("myresources/fonts/Papyrus.ttf", 26)
```

Any help is appreciated. I'll just be doing more productive things meanwhile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("SansitaOne.tff",25)` instead.`SysFont` doesn't require whole path.But be sure your font is in the Windows font directory.Also you should write `pygame.init()` not that one, `font.init` is not necessary.

> To install a font
>
> Open Fonts by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button,
>   clicking Control Panel, clicking Appearance and Personalization, and
>   then clicking Fonts.
>
> Then drag your font to there. That's all.

You should see this screen, drag your font here.

[image]

Comment: That will do. I was hoping I could have this work on a thumb drive but I think this is as close as I will get to it working thanks.